# DataBinding Access From Folder

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding

I am Using DataBinding in My Project in android. It Work's fine In My MainActivity.
After I am Using New Activity For DataBinding. But This Time I am Create A New Package,Inside The New Package I am Create An Activity and Using DataBinding But In This time Error occurs In Automatically Created Databinding Activity.

I am Open The Automatically create File I cant Edit The File.What Will do.
please help me to solve this  problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the first letter of your package name is in lowercase.